# How to change text of the TextBlock on the button?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I got a button with an led light and a TextBlock, the led light will change depend of some rules. Everything works correctly when I use it in DataTamplate. When I want to move it to ResourceDictionay I don't know how to set a text of a TextBlock.

```
<views:BaseView.Resources>
    <views:SwapBooleanValueConverter x:Key="SwapBooleanValueConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FlowStagesTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="TurulStageButton"
                    Tag="{Binding ID}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.OnButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FlowStageButton}"
                    Style="{Binding FlowStageDisplayStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200">
                    <Rectangle Width="4" Height="30" Fill="#64dd17" Margin="0,0,10,1" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FlowStageName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</views:BaseView.Resources>
<StackPanel Background="#263238">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FlowStagesSubMenu}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlowStagesTemplate}" 
              BorderThickness="0" Background="#263238" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

So now I would like to move this to DictionaryResources:

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleGreen" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200">
                    <Rectangle Width="4" Height="30" Fill="#64dd17" Margin="0,0,10,1" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

So how do I bind the text of the TextBlock to `Text="{Binding FlowStageName}"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.FlowStageName,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
```

Comment: You save my day! Thank you !